# Gateway configuration is not working

Tags: linux, virtualbox, route

I have three virtual machines, vm1, gwvm and vm2. gwvm has two interfaces, one connected to vm1 and other connected to vm2. Following image has IP and route details,

[image: gwvm details of gateway VM]

[image]

[image]

Here vm1 and vm2 are in different subnet and I am trying to enable the vms to communicate using a gateway VM.

- from gwvm I can ping vm1 and vm2
- from vm1 and vm2 I can ping both interfaces of gwvm
- When I ping from vm1 to vm2 or oposite way is not working, everything seems to be in place.

Can someone help me why I am not able to ping from vm1 to vm2 ?

Comment: Please add a comment for down voting, it will help me next time when I post question.

Comment: Downvoting is done when post is not useful, unclear or shows no research effort. Here it was provavel because of giving screenshots instead of just the relevant text *as text*. You  state that you have no clue (I just take your word for that) but no question.

Comment: Thank you, I accept your suggestion, I will edit the question statement. I didn't put all ip and route details in words just avoid other thoughts on readers, human errors and wrong configuration etc. While taking screen shot I was care-full not to put any irrelevant information but give all the information required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you check forwarding option ?

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
```

try

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

note that unless told otherwise unix host do not forward from one interface to another.

my thanks goes to http://www.ducea.com/2006/08/01/how-to-enable-ip-forwarding-in-linux/

Comment: I have added static route, referring this link http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/04/route-examples/. I will check the link you provided.

Comment: I was about to say: do not mistake routing and forwarding. Glad this solve your problem.